# Index text files with tags and search

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've got a SQL Server database full of documents that I'd like to extract into text files and index according to particular tags in the docs and tags that I add.

Is there a tag-based text indexing API or library out there I can use? As a follow-up, I also need a client that can search these things.

I'm thinking about extracting the docs out as XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into SQL Server Full Text to search text/varchar data?

Otherwise, you can use Indexing Services / Windows Search.  The great thing about this option is that you can use custom, searchable meta tags.

Comment: I'm thinking more something I can deploy on a web server and/or use a client search tool to pick up data.

Comment: Not sure if I follow.  Either solution (Full Text vs Indexing Services / Windows Search) will allow for web-based searching of documents.  Both have APIs (T-SQL in the case of Full Text).